# Reuse connection among DbContext instances in unit test

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, xunit.net

I'm trying to setup some unit tests using EntityFramework 5, SQL Server Compact 4 and Xunit.

I'm using different context instances because I'm testing a ASP MVC app and I need to test the behavior of some update operations over detached entities.

```
[Fact, AutoRollback]
public void TestConnection()
{
    using (var connection = this.GetDbConnection())
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext(connection, false))
        {
            // Do database stuff
        }

        using (var context = new MyContext(connection, false))
        {
            // Do database stuff
        }
    }
}

public DbConnection GetDbConnection()
{
    string dataSource = "|DataDirectory|\\MyDb.sdf";

    var sqlBuilder = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;

    return new SqlCeConnection(sqlBuilder.ToString());
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
System.Data.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
System.InvalidOperationException : The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope.
```

I know I can't open multiple DbContext instances inside a TransactionScope (that is probably what Xunit does when you put a FallbackAttribute in your method), so that's why I'm creating the connection beforehand.

If I try to open the connection myself, it still does not work:

```
using (var connection = this.GetDbConnection())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var context = new MyContext(connection, false))
    {
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException : EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection.
```

Does any one know how to solve that issue?

**EDIT**

The test classes that deal with the Db extend a "DomainFactsBase" where the database is initialized as the following:

```
public DomainFactsBase()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
    using (var context = new MyContext(GetDbConnection(), true))
        context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

**EDIT**

I can sucessfully run tests with autorollback when I create only one context instance. This was accomplished following the instructions in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/diego/archive/2012/01/26/exception-from-dbcontext-api-entityconnection-can-only-be-constructed-with-a-closed-dbconnection.aspx). I have a extension method:

```
public static void OpenConnection(this DbContext context)
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();
}
```

And I call it right after creating the context in the tests:

```
[Fact, AutoRollback]
public void SomeFact()
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.OpenConnection();

            // Do stuff
    }
}
```

That work with no problems. They arise when I try to open the context more than once in the same fact (with AutoRollback enabled), as I examplified in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the database outside of the test. You can do this inside of the test class's constructor.

```cs
public MyTestClass()
{
    using (var db = new MyContext(GetDbConnection(), true))
    {
        db.Database.Initialize(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Brice, but all my database test classes extend a "DomainFactsBase" class where the database is initialized as you suggested.